How do I add a method and use it in a letter template?
I need to add a custom method and use it in the template of the email that goes to the user after registration to confirm his account. How can I do this?

It was necessary to write your own module, in which a Block containing a custom method would be initialized. You can also call it in a template created in the same template, and already use the template and the block in the letter template via {{block}}
